# Confusion with Rails 3 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I upgrade my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.0.5. One issue in utf8 encoding makes me really confused:

In Rails 2.3.5 version, when I print a Japanese phrase, for example,

```
    str = "保守性1"        
    p str
    #output: => "\344\277\235\345\256\210\346\200\2471"`
```

Meanwhile, in Rails 3.0.5 version, the same code will return:

```
    str = "保守性1"
    p str
    #output: => "保守性1"
```

I have googled alot but no result. Could you please figure out any possible reason for this issue?

I want to keep the same output as in Rails 2.3.5 version. Any idea is very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: good question. maybe is due to rails c.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1238 try to put "magic comment"

```
# coding: utf-8
```

to the top of your non-ASCII script.